# node.js validation and error handling for user data input, and data update

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express, mongoose

heloo, i have an APIs that am building and i need proper validation to handle user input for me, if the user enter an empty field, or if the user wants to edit his data he needs to enter and ID that the validator should check, and should handle if the input is undefined or null.

```
router.post('/update',function(req,res){

var language = req.body.language,
    country_id = req.body.country_id,
    city_id = req.body.city_id,
    pickup_points = req.body.pickup_points,
    static_address = req.body.static_address,
    address_id= req.body.address_id;

// if(address_id == null || address_id == undefined ){
//  res.json({success: false, message : "address wasn't updated"});

// }else{

    Address.findById(address_id,function(err,address){
    if(err) {res.json({success:false , message:"please enter a valid address Id"});
    }
    });
    req.assert('address_id', 'Invalid address id').notEmpty();
     var errors = req.validationErrors();
     if (errors) {
     res.json({success:false,message:"please enter address ID " });

     }

    Address.findById(address_id,function(err,address){
        address.language = req.body.language != null && req.body.language !=undefined ? req.body.language : address.language;
        address.country_id = req.body.country_id != null && req.body.country_id !=undefined ? req.body.country_id : address.country_id;
        address.city_id = req.body.city_id != null && req.body.city_id !=undefined ? req.body.city_id : address.city_id;
        address.pickup_points = req.body.pickup_points != null && req.body.pickup_points !=undefined ? address.pickup_points.push(req.body.pickup_points) : address.pickup_points;
        address.static_address = req.body.static_address != null && req.body.static_address !=undefined ? req.body.static_address : address.static_address;

        address.save(function(err,student){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{

            res.json({success : true , message : "address successfully updated"  });}
        });
    });
// }
```

this is a code sample, and how i've approached validation, but if the id was not found in the database the code crashes